# Points, Area and Volume - Parallelogram and tilted box

Tags: linear-algebra

How to solve the following problem in an systematic way? (without plotting)

Let $P = (1,0,-1)$, $Q = (1,1,1)$, and $R = (2,2,1)$. Choose $S$ so that $PQRS$ is a parallelogram, and compute its area. Choose $T$,$U$,$V$ so that $OPQRSTUV$ is a tilted box, and compute its volume.

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: I have an intuitive answer that I am not very satisfied. Let's denote the vector as $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Then, I note, P and Q have the same $x_1$, Q and R have the same $x_3$. Thus, Q should be their adjacent point. Since, P has $x_2 = 0$ and R = $x_2 = 2$. I have $S = (2,1-1)$. I have yet to compute the area but I think it can be done through determination. Then, I got absolutely confused in figuring $T,U,V$ as well as $O$. I feel like I am not doing in a systematic way.

Comment: Alright. Suppose S is correct, then I assume we can use cross product to find the area of the parallelogram. That is, $|| \vec{PQ}  \times \vec{PR} ||$ = 3

Comment: So far, so good. You can use a determinant to compute the volume of the tilted box. $O$ is almost certainly the origin, so I’m guessing that they want the other side of the box to be congruent to the parallelogram that you just built but with one vertex at the origin.

Comment: @amd Two questions. Must $O$ be at the origin? I thought the restriction is the remaining 4 vectors ($O,T,U,V$) have to make up a tilted box so it can be any of those points. Assume, it can be at the origin, then can i just subtract one of the parallelogram vectors so that one of the parallelogram vector is at the origin and then I deduce the remaining vectors so that all the vectors are "shifted nicely". For example, "$Q' = Q-Q$", "$P' = P-Q$", "$R' = R-Q$",  "$S' =S-Q$".

Comment: There needs to be *some* definite point specified by the problem, otherwise the second half doesn’t have a unique solution. By convention, the origin is often labeled $O$.